# Specification of the categorical variables in a linear model in r

Tags: regression, linear

I have three variables:

- number of house sales
- month (in couples)
- region of a city (N-W-E-S)

and I want to create a linear model with the region and the month as the predictors with this form

$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2x_j + \epsilon_{ij}$

The problem I´m finding is that the coefficients given by the model seem strange to me according to the data, but maybe they´re not, a little bit of insight would be appreciated.

```
month <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
region <-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
sales <-c(85, 107,61, 22, 40, 65, 58,51,60,41,45,27,15,30,68,63,28,3,57,12,36,21,10,16)
```

Firtly, as the categorical variables are defined as numerical, I convert them to integers, so the model would perform with the variable as a whole, and not its levels, and then I create the model.

```
data <- cbind(sales, month, region)
data <- as.data.frame(data)

data$month <- as.integer(data$month)
data$region <- as.integer(data$region)

salesmod <- lm(sales ~ month + region, data=data)
summary(salesmod)
```

And these are the coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   82.808     13.457   6.154 4.18e-06 ***
month         -9.279      2.467  -3.761  0.00115 ** 
region        -3.117      3.769  -0.827  0.41755    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 20.64 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4139,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.358 
F-statistic: 7.414 on 2 and 21 DF,  p-value: 0.003665
```

The result looks pretty normal at first sight. Variable month is significant and variable region is not. However, if you take a look at the data, the region is obviously significant in the model. I think I did something wrong in the specification of the variables. But unless you define them as integers the function *lm* performs the model for each class.

Any help would be appreciated it.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert categorical predictors to numeric, then the model assumes that the outcome is linearly related to those numeric values. That's clearly not the case in your data. If you changed the ordering of your 4 regions you would change that underlying assumption about which region has the greatest influence on outcome. Yet the actual differences between, say, `W` and `E` areas wouldn't actually be different

That's precisely *why* "the function `lm` performs the model for each class" for an unordered categorical variable. When you have a 4-level unordered categorical variable, it counts as 3 predictors. Typical modeling returns coefficients for the differences of the outcome associations of each of three levels versus that of the reference category (which is subsumed into the intercept of the model).

Comment: Txs for the answer. But how do I perform the model with just the two betas as I specified in the question? If I define the vectors as factors it does the regression for the each level of the variable, and I dont want that

Comment: @shark.caller you can't use just 1 coefficient for an unordered categorical predictor that has more than 2 levels. You need to specify 1 coefficient per level beyond the first. You then can use things like ANOVA to evaluate the overall contribution of the predictor to the model, but you have to start with the full model and all those coefficients.

Comment: If you run lm(sales ~ factor(region)) followed by car::Anova() you'll find that region is not significant at alpha = 0.05.  It's also not significant when you run an ANCOVA by adding month as a covariate with same slope lm(sales ~ month + factor(region)) or with separate slopes lm(sales ~ month * factor(region))